# perl gzip unexpected end of file

Tags: perl, file, gzip, output

I consistently write data into the archive. After each record I need to know the size of the resulting file. To solve this problem, I use the buffer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature 'say';
use IO::Compress::Gzip qw| $GzipError :flush |;


my $out_file_name = 'out.gz';
my $buf;

open my $out, '>', $out_file_name;

my $ft = Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH;

my $gzip = IO::Compress::Gzip->new(\$buf);
$gzip->print("some data");
$gzip->flush($ft);

$gzip->print("some data2");
$gzip->flush($ft);

print $out $buf;

$gzip->close;
close $out;
```

When the script has finished, I test the result and get the following error:

```
$ gzip -cd out.gz
some data1
some data2
gzip: out.gz: unexpected end of file
```

Why this error occurs. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must close the gzip stream *before* writing `$buf` to your output file:

```
$gzip->close;
print $out $buf;
close $out;
```

The `$gzip->close` call writes some terminating data to the end of the buffer to complete the gzip encoding. In your example, you're not writing this data to the file, so when you try to unzip it later, gzip can't find data that it's expecting to see there.